# How can I parse a selected table from webpage with Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-table

I wish to parse the results table from a local sport event (the page basically just contain a table), but when I try with the script below I just get the "menu", not the actual result list. What am I missing?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

site = "https://rittresultater.no/nb/sb_tid/923?pv2=11027&pv1=U"
html = urlopen(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml") #BeautifulSoup(urlopen(html, "lxml"))

table = soup.select("table")
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
print.df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because there are two `<table>`s on that page. You can either query on the class name of the table you want (in this case `.table-condensed`) using the `class_` parameter of the `find()` function, or you can just grab the second table in the list of all tables using the `find_all()` function.

Solution 1:

```
table = soup.find('table', class_='table-condensed')
print(table)
```

Solution 2:

```
tables = soup.find_all('table')
print(tables[1])
```